# Microsoft Teams and Java integration

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-teams

I want to send private messages to people from Java and I don't know how.
I would be grateful for any clues. I have already tried using Microsoft Graph API but I have no idea how to use it with a bot-like account (and I don't know how to create one).

Comment: There are ample docs and other questions that can show you how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to [register your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#1-register-your-app)
2. [Configure permissions for Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#2-configure-permissions-for-microsoft-graph) according to graph API you are planning to use.
3. [Get administrator consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#3-get-administrator-consent)
4. [Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider based on scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS). Samples for Java is available in doc.
5. Send chatMessage in a channel or a chat. Refer [Java examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=java#request)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to interact with Microsoft Teams REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0